# How do I add a hover image transition without breaking my code?

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I put some HTML/CSS together in order to customize a content block on Squarespace. 4 images floating inline. I want to hover on the image and for it to fade into another image, creating the illusion of zooming out. Everytime I try to implement the commands to do this, I break it. The new image isn't centered on the existing image and in some cases, finds a new position on the page. I want to keep the current structure intact.

Can someone please help me with adding the new code in order to achieve this?

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.header {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 32px;
}

.row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    /* IE10 */
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    /* IE10 */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0 4px;
}


.column {
    -ms-flex: 25%;
    flex: 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
    padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
    margin-top: 8px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .column {
        -ms-flex: 50%;
        flex: 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .column {
        -ms-flex: 100%;
        flex: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}

div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Photo Grid -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <img src="https://vivianeart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/sd2_png.png" style="width:100%">
        <div class="desc">Sarah Nordean</div>

    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img src="https://vivianeart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/sct2_png.png" style="width:100%">
        <div class="desc">Scott Everingham</div>

    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img src="https://vivianeart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/sd3_png.png" style="width:100%">
        <div class="desc">Serena Beaulieu</div>

    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img src="https://vivianeart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/sd4_png.png" style="width:100%">
        <div class="desc">Shawn Evans</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you exactly want more clearly?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Change Image on Hover in CSS</title>
<style>
    .card {
        width: 130px;
        height: 195px;
        background: url("images/card-back.jpg") no-repeat;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .card:hover {
        background: url("images/card-front.jpg") no-repeat;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card"></div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I need to implement this code to each image.

Comment: I have put the code from your comment in an answer snippet (as I can't put a snippet in a comment). Could you have a look and check that that is the effect you want? Where are the images that are to be at the back of the 4 images shown?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: this is now an answer to how to make one image fade into another on the given code.

I found that using the given card-changing code caused flickering on hover so I have changed it slightly so that existing main code remains as is except each img is wrapped in a div. This has as background-image the image that will be faded into. Some CSS is added to make the transition to/from opacity on hover

Here is the complete code, as given in the question with the additions listed above:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 32px;
}

.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
}


.column {
  -ms-flex: 25%; 
  flex: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    -ms-flex: 50%;
    flex: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    -ms-flex: 100%;
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
/* ADDED CSS */
div.background {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  background-position: 0px 8px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat no-repeat;
  background-size:contain;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
img { opacity : 1; transition:opacity 0.3s; }
img:hover { opacity : 0;}
</style>
<body>

<!-- Photo Grid -->
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="column">
    <div class="background" style="background-image:url(https://vivianeart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/sct2_png.png);"> 
      <img src="https://vivianeart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/sd2_png.png" style="width:100%;">
    </div>  
    <div class="desc">Sarah Nordean</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="background" style="background-image:url(https://vivianeart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/sd3_png.png);">
      <img src="https://vivianeart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/sct2_png.png" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="desc">Scott Everingham</div>
  
  </div>  
  <div class="column">
    <div class="background" style="background-image:url(https://vivianeart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/sd4_png.png);">
      <img src="https://vivianeart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/sd3_png.png" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="desc">Serena Beaulieu</div>

  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="background" style="background-image:url(https://vivianeart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/sd2_png.png);">
      <img src="https://vivianeart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/sd4_png.png" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="desc">Shawn Evans</div>
   
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

This is the original text in this answer post asking for clarification.
This wasn't claiming to be an answer but was asking for clarification of some code which cannot be done in a comment.

Here is the code Al Taljana put in a comment - with background-colors put in by me in lieu of actual images. Could you verify that this is the effect you want - basically just changing one image for another? (Run the snippet and hover over the rectangle).

```css
 .card { width: 130px; height: 195px; background: url("images/card-back.jpg") no-repeat; display: inline-block; background-color:magenta; }
 .card:hover { background: url("images/card-front.jpg") no-repeat; background-color: cyan; }
```

```html
 <div class="card">
 </div>
```

Comment: yes thank you so much! I had to fix my code as it was non-responsive, I will update.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I am not too sure about what are the exact images that you will like to use, but here is a template of how the code for it to work.

```css
img {
    transition: all linear 0.7s;
}

.box {
    position: relative;

}

img.hover-img {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}

.box:hover img.hover-img {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <img class="hover-img" src="https://www.redbridgenet.com/wp-content/uploads/html5.png" alt="Image name"
        width="300" height="300">
    <img src="https://wwwtalks.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/logo-2582748_640-300x300.png" alt="Image name" width="300" height="300">
</div>
```